# Decode the bytes

Tags: python, byte, decode, porting

Following piece of code is from zipfile.py.

```
   self.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader())

   def FileHeader(self):

       header = struct.pack(structFileHeader, stringFileHeader,
                 self.extract_version, self.reserved, flag_bits,
                 self.compress_type, CRC, dosdate, CRC,
                 compress_size, file_size,
                 len(filename), len(extra))
       return header + filename + extra
```

In some other file:

```
  // Some other codes.....


  zip_file = zip_dir(self.upload_dir)

  zip_file.getvalue()
```

**My Question:**

The result of 'zip_file.getvalue()' is as follows:

...b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00O>\x9f\xec\x04\xd0\x06\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00index.htmlyellowPK\x01\x02\x14\x03\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x84\x93O>\x9f\xec\x04\xd0\x06\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00index.htmlPK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x008\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

If I try to decode i.e.

zip_file.getvalue().decode()

it says:

'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 14: unexpected code byte

Is it possible to decode the above?

Comment: The `getvalue()` result is a binary ZIP representation. What do you expect from "decoding" it? It's not text, so you can't decode it to Unicode. I don't know what you're trying to achieve - do you want to open a ZIP file??

Comment: The value I'm getting above is b'something'. I just want to convert b'something' to 'something'? I'm not sure if this can be done.

Comment: It just does not make sense. You should first understand the difference between bytes and strings in Python 3. The above is the binary content of a ZIP file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing to decode. The bytes make up a zip file, and you can extract the contents of the archive with creative use of `zipfile`.